# C++ Object vs Struct Memory Overhead

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, struct

I need to create very large arrays of RGB values for image processing. The actual operations that will be performed on them are simple—just orthogonal projection to see how similar two colors are—but every bit counts with regards to memory. I am thinking about storing images as a double pointer to structs with 3 chars in them, which I thought would be the most memory efficent way, but I know it is usually recommended to use wrapper classes. By question is how trivial is the memory overhead for creating a class vs a struct and using some sort of wrapper vs using a double pointer.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no difference between

```
class X
{
  public: 
     T1 x;
     T2 y;
     T3 z;
}
```

and

```
struct X
{
     T1 x;
     T2 y;
     T3 z;
};
```

If you add virtual functions to the class, yes, it will add to the storage. But nothing else will make any difference between `class` and `struct` (in fact, it's possible to have virtual members in `struct` too - although it is typical to distinguish between `struct` and `class` by having member functions and (non-trivial) constructors only for classes).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback